# What is Qconfig in QISKit and how do I set it up?

Tags: programming, qiskit

To use certain things in QISKIt, such as acessing the real quantum processors, it seems that there is a file 'Qconfig.py'. That needs to be set up.

How do I do this?

Comment: Any solutions on this problem: cannot import name 'register' from 'qiskit'

Comment: @SathieshKaliy The 'register' command has now been deprecated. See how to do it with the current Qiskit version at https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get access to the real devices and remote simulators, you need to have an account with the [IBM Q Experience](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/). Once you do, you can get your API key from the account page.

Once you have the API key, you can set up a Qconfig file. Let's assume that you want to run things from the [QISKit tutorial](https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-tutorial). The Qconfig file can then be set up by editing the file located [here](https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-tutorial/blob/master/Qconfig.py.template).

You just need to replace the line

```
APItoken = None
```

with

```
APItoken = "randomstringoflettersandnumbersyoucopiedfromthewebsite"
```

Where the stuff within the quotation marks should be your actual API token.

You also need to rename the file from 'Qconfig.py.template' to just `Qconfig.py`.

Now you need to import the information from this file in your programs. This will depend on where you program sits in your computer relative to the Qconfig file.

If the `.py` or `.ipynb` file containing your program is sitting in the same directory as 'Qconfig.py', you can import with just

```
import Qconfig
qx_config = {
    "APItoken": Qconfig.APItoken,
    "url": Qconfig.config['url']}
```

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    qx_config = {
        "APItoken":"YOUR_TOKEN_HERE",
        "url":"https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/api"}

and then register your connection to the API with

register(qx_config['APItoken'], qx_config['url'])

If your `.py` or `.ipynb` is one directory level down, such as for [this](https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-tutorial/tree/master/hello_world) you'll need to have the lines

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
```

before you try to import. This tells the program to look for the Qconfig file in the directory above instead.